# Connecting to a server's local host (PHP programming)

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

I'm just an amateur when it comes to PHP programming and I was hoping if you could help me in this problem of mine. I just started learning php last week and my problem is that i cant find a way on how to connect to a server computer's local host. basically the code in my global.php is this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
session_start();

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "carlog";

mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die (mysql_error());
?>
```

so i'm connected to the server computer via a viritual router. I was hoping that the client computer could connect to the server's local host. I tried changing the "localhost" to the server's IP add but nothing happened. the client computer wasn;t able to connect to the server (only to its own localhost)

I would be really happy if anyone of you could help me in this problem of mine. thank you

Comment: Is the webserver and mysql running on the same computer?

Comment: I don't understand the set up? Also, if you're new to learning PHP, don't use `mysql_*` functions. They're deprecated. Check out MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Better to learn PHP with new technologies, use PDO instead of `mysql_*` functions. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Which "Server Software" are you using?

Comment: try using the ip address with port as well ..... Default MySQL port is 3306

Comment: Are you sure that the server works and it's accessible when you type `mysql -uroot` to the console?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if any errors are being thrown right now, the `error_reporting(0);` at the top is preventing the system from telling you what it's seeing.

Secondly, as others have pointed out, please try and see if you can use PDO or MySQLi instead of the `mysql_connect()` family, as it is indeed deprecated and scheduled for removal from PHP in the future.

Thirdly, ensure that MySQL server is running on the default port of 3306, has no firewall closing it off, is running, etc, on the remote server :)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of PHP are you running? This method is deprecated. I recommend you to check out how to set-up a PDO connection. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Try ping  in your terminal and check if you can reach it. Use this IP in your code.

Hiding all the errors isnt helping you debugging your issue. 
Use:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and check the output